# Stream file to user for download in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, api, express, stream

I would like to ask you for help with REST API in Node / Express.

I'm calling a vendor API to get a label in PDF format, and then I need to send it to a user which is calling the API.

I'm using the `request` npm package to call another API. I have also tried `node-fetch` but with no luck.

Example code:

```
retrieveLabel(req, res, next) {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'apiUrl' + 'shipments/xxx/label',
    headers: {
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      authorization: xxxToken,
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  request(options, (error, response, results) => {
    // NO idea how to send it as reponse...


  });
}
```

In console there is response with type string, starting with something like this:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj
<
</Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Width 1171 /Height 1676 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /BitsPerComponent 8 /Decode [0 1 0 1 0 1] /Interpolate false /Filter /FlateDecode /DecodeParms<
</Predictor 12 /Colors 3 /Columns 1171 >>
 /Length 61782 >>
stream
X���o�]�}'�;!Yl"�ɠh����x�H&�r�h�@(�3[ҋHK"�r+)K�q{kYL���fl���H�)��@�By�v�Ԭ\Z��3�-�5�Զ*PEJ���EU�����G�Ϲ�v���t��S��n���s�sn��>�y���1y��y��r'��Nrȝ��;�
 wݓ�Ν;�m��b�X,��b�X,s�D �MO?�܊,6@rK&''w����b���266�H�%��_~��r�C���X,�e�K��������U��۲e���%+�������|���*��?pr �@�$7��In���r'��Nrȝ�0���o���|עʑ#Gn�������u�s��Z���ɓqe��|U >��9z�%�ٳw
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `response` from the API is a readable stream. Your `res` (res to the http request from your website client) is a writeable stream. Easiest way to accomplish your goal is to pipe the readable stream into the writable, like this:

```
retrieveLabel(req, res, next) {
    //...
    request(options, (error, response, results) => {
        response.pipe(res);
    });
    //...
```

You can get more information on stream piping from the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) on streams.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for you answer, but I still cannot get it. I tried with ```fs.createWriteStream```, with response.pipe(res) and also with adding to the header 'application/pdf' type but with no luck.

With pipe, I'm getting error -> ```TypeError: dest.end is not a function```

Comment: Hi David, I also found some example with request npm package ->
```request(options)
                    .on('error', (err) => {
                        console.log('error', err)
                    })
                    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('Label.pdf'))
                    .on('finish', (response) => {
                        console.log('success', response);
                        return res.send({ error: false, message: 'success' });
                    });```

It is almost what I want, but file is saving on API destination... It is not asking user to save it.